# Are Rabbi Akiva's opinions disproportionately followed?

Tags: history, machlokes, tannaim, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

I understand that [Rabbi Akiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi_Akiva) was the foremost rabbinic leader of his time, and after the Bar Kochba revolt [his students were the primary Tanaaim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaim#Generations), and they also were responsible for organizing the early Talmudic literature which is regarded as being in accord with Rabbi Akiva (Sanhedrin 86a).

But in cases where the Tanaaim disagreed, are his opinions accepted more than the opinions of the other Tanaaim of Rabbi Akiva’s generation, or do we often follow different opinions?

Secondarily, *if* his opinions are typically the opinions we follow, do we have any basis to say whether or not the historical contingency of his position was responsible for his opinions being what we follow? For example, can we tell whether those opinions already happened to be the predominant ones, or he just happened to be among the majority of Tanaaim? Or if not, is there any basis for speculating on whether the position of his students just practically meant Rabbi Akiva's opinions would be the ones we follow?

Comment: דאיתא בגליא רזיא תקס"ד פעמים נזכר ר"ע בש"ס והלכה כמותו שע"ה פעמים